# setup Mozilla Pontoon on Debian

Tags: debian, mozilla

I've been trying to set up Mozilla Pontoon on my website, which is hosted on a Debian server, by following the [Developer Setup instructions](https://mozilla-pontoon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/setup.html), but it's getting hung up on step 26/27:

```
 Step 26/27 : RUN chown -R app:app /app
 ---> Running in 8bcgdg692f1e
```

and that's where it stops. I followed all of the steps preceding `make run`.

any ideas on how I can get Pontoon running?